# Could not find a declaration file for module 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use bootstrap js in angular 11 project and when I import the bootstrap class/js in my component class I am getting below error

It was not happening in bootstrap 5 alpha but happening in final version, any idea?

```
Error: src/app/components/ba-carousel/ba-carousel.component.ts:3:23 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'. '/Users/aniruddh/bootstrap-angular/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/bootstrap` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';`

3 import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

component code:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ba-carousel',
  templateUrl: './ba-carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ba-carousel.component.scss']
})
export class BaCarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  modalDirect: Bootstrap.Modal;
  @ViewChild('demoModal') input;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Comment: You tired install bootstrap types? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/bootstrap`

Comment: @enno.void yes, already installed and able to do auto-complete in webstorm successfullly

Comment: Possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72269109/3758916